# Subversion: how to auto update a repository

Tags: svn

With subversion is there a way to automatically update a repository at say 6am every morning?

Answer (score 4):

To run a command to update an SVN working copy at 6:00 am every morning on Windows:

```
at 06:00 /every:M,T,W,Th,F,S,Su svn up path\to\wc
```

You could take out `S` and `Su` to have it only run on weekdays.

Comment: I am assuming that by 'repository' you mean _working copy_ btw.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by command line and scheduler build on your OS.

Comment: windows has an 'at' command. Something like: `at 6am foo.exe`

Comment: Ok. I'm using Windows XP. Yea i can use windows schedule to kick it off. Just wondering what command line query to use

Comment: (actually it's almost certainly not exactly that; I can't recall from the top of my head, maybe svn -u, but someone else will confirm soon :)

Answer (score 0):

You can write a small script for this.